# Could not access file “citus”:no such file or directory;

Tags: postgresql, citus

when i start postgres-14, then tell me "Could not access file “citus”:no such file or directory;"
i have insetlled citus. but i still don't start postgres-14.can you help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It looks like you did not install citus properly. Did you try to install it from source, or os packages? Can you confirm that it is installed.

This error happens when you have citus in `shared_preload_libraries` but you have not installed `citus.so` file in the correct directory.